# Unable to retrieve credentials of the Azure Keyvault via an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I have the following pipeline implemented in ADF which works correctly.

[image]

I found some code that retrieves the credentials in the Azure Keyvault and when the code is executed in a Python notebook then it works in the same way as the pipeline.

```
from notebookutils import mssparkutils
workspacetype = 'dev'

credentials1 = mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret(f'data-'{workspacetype}'-kv','credential1')
credentials2 = mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret(f'data-{workspacetype}-kv','credential2')
```

I converted the notebook into a pipeline, that is, I don't have the web activities and the set variables but just the notebook. Nonetheless, when the new pipeline is executed I receive a 400 error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret.: java.lang.Exception: Access token couldn't be obtained {"result":"DependencyError","errorId":"BadRequest","errorMessage":"LSRServiceException is [{\"StatusCode\":400
```

It seems that the code I have cannot be used to retrieve the credentials from the keyvault when the notebook is converted into a pipeline. I'd like to confirm from experts if this is truly the case or if I need to enable some permission in my ADF.

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Could you please confirm this? are you using synapse notebook or spark cluster notebook?

Comment: Synapse notebook

Answer (score 0):

1. Have created a secret in Azure key Vault.
   [image]
2. Next created a notebook in synapse analytics workspace.
   [image]
3. Provided Get and List permissions to synapse analytics workspace from azure key vault. Kindly refer below link to add access policy.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal
   [image]
4. Notebook contains code retrieving secret from key vault.

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
token_library = sc._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.TokenLibrary
connection_string = token_library.getSecret('<keyvaultname>','<secretname>')
print(connection_string)
```

5. Once created notebook, ran the code and able to get secret value.
6. Next tried to run notebook in pipeline and got below error,
   [image]
   [image]
7. As per below reference, there is some issue in product.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/655099/34cannot-acquire-msi-token-for-a-vault-audience34.html
8. Modified language to C# with below code and pipeline executed successfully,

```
using Microsoft.Spark.Extensions.Azure.Synapse.Analytics.Utils;
string connectionString = TokenLibrary.GetSecret("<keyvaultname>", "<secretname>", "<linkedservicename>");
Console.WriteLine(connectionString)
```

[image]